# Не работает Theme Editor в Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: Вот примерно так ведет себя Theme Editor при его открытии]

Как сделать что бы он заработал?
Последняя версия Android Studio

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53891582/android-studio-3-3-rc3-theme-editor-missing полагаю, это еще актуально

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, его и вправду отключили